# Convert a specific string in datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am trying to update a column that contain a string on mysql and send to another column with datetime. I am using the following query

```
update 2001080_t val
set val.datetimestamp = convert (val.NotUsed4, datetime)
```

But the problem that the string is not on the correct format

```
   Example:
  `string` 010716000000
  ideal way 2016-07-01 00:00:00
  results from query:  2001-07-16 00:00:00
```

How to change the reading way?

Comment: Is there ever going to be an instance where it is 1999 or lower?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could manipulate the dates yourself, since MySQL will never really recognize a date in that manner, Like so:

```
SELECT CONCAT(IF(RIGHT(LEFT('010716000000',6),2) < 30, '20', '19'),
RIGHT(LEFT('010716000000',6),2), '-', RIGHT(LEFT('010716000000',4),2),
'-', LEFT('010716000000',2));
```

So your query would look like this.

```
UPDATE 2001080_t val
SET val.datetimestamp = CONCAT(IF(RIGHT(LEFT(val.NotUsed4,6),2) < 30, '20', '19'),
RIGHT(LEFT(val.NotUsed4,6),2), '-',
RIGHT(LEFT(val.NotUsed4,4),2), '-',
LEFT(val.NotUsed4,2));
```

If you have to do this often, I would reccomend making a function for it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION hello (myIntDate INT(12))
RETURNS DATETIME
RETURN CONCAT(IF(RIGHT(LEFT(myIntDate,6),2) < 30, '20', '19'),
    RIGHT(LEFT(myIntDate,6),2), '-',
    RIGHT(LEFT(myIntDate,4),2), '-',
    LEFT(myIntDate,2));
```

*Edit: Added support that if the year is > 30, it is considered a 1900 date.*

Comment: I saw there are 6 zeros at the end. If there are any that need time, you can apply the same technique.